# Are there English equivalents to the Japanese saying, “There’s a god who puts you down as well as a god who picks you up”?

Tags: phrases, idioms, popular-refrains

There is an old Japanese saying, “捨てる神あれば、拾う神あり-Suterukami areba hirou kami ari,” meaning “There’s a god who puts you down as well as a god who picks up you.” In other words, “In this world, some people help you, and some people harm you” or “Fortune and misfortune come alternately.”

For example, when you are fired from an IT company, and then hired by its rival company with a higher salary three months later, your peers will say to you “You're a lucky man. There’s a god who throws you away as well as a god who picks you up.”

I’m curious to know if there are similar sayings in English to “Suterukami areba hirou kami ari.”

Comment: Something to be careful of is that when referring to Japanese (Shinto?) _gods_, they are a generic term and thus lower case "g". When translating to English, there's a distinction between "God" (capital G, the one deity in Western religions) and "god" (any other deity, unrecognized by Western religions). What I'm saying is that you don't write "God" when you are referring to one of several "gods" in a polytheistic faith. From the structure of the saying, it sounds like you're talking about two different gods.

Comment: As this is an Japanese old saying, it would presuppose Shinto gods. I corrected the spelling accordingly. I presume however, we can also extrapolate God in the meaning of "There’s time that God puts you down, and picks you up sometimes” as in “The Lord giveth, and the Lord taketh away," suggested by Scott Centoni.

Comment: @Yoichi, I love your questions :)  The closest in English is "one door closes, another opens."  For an excellent example of this, carefully watch _The sound of music_.  (Incidentally, all students of English should carefully study this film, as it's a fundamental musical-linguistic experience of 20th C English. For example, it contains "do-re-mi" which is the second most important rhyme in English after the alphabet song.) "Lord giveth, Lord taketh away" is more "biblical/Christian/religious" than the more general doors open/close.

Comment: Yoichi, one thing that immediately comes to mind for me is the flippant, badass, random, whacky, "you'll never know what will happen next" nature of the **Greek gods** in homeric writings, in the homeric era.  Here in the west we often contrast that with our modern, absolute, nobody-else-but-me, one-truth-only, monotheistic Christian/Muslim/Jewish God. I bet, there were some homeric-like phrases on what you describe. The ONLY modern thing I can think of is "The gods must be crazy!" which is a comedy film about the concept you describe, from an African tribesman's view. (Hilarious film BTW.)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Probably the closest English saying to this is "The Lord giveth, and the Lord taketh away," which is actually a misquote of [Job 1:21](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Job%201:21&version=KJV):

> And said, Naked came I out of my mother's womb, and naked shall I return thither: the Lord gave, and the Lord hath taken away; blessed be the name of the Lord.

Comment: I think you should dig into more pagan resources than the Bible, because what Yoichi meant was "There are deities/gods who gives, and yet other deities/gods who takes away". In Hindu trinity - Trimurthi, an almighty with a face of creation, another face of maintenance, another face of destruction.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: fact is, you're not going to find any widely used religious sayings in English that are not based on Christianity. And this saying is really the exact monotheistic equivalent of the Japanese one.

Comment: Inhowfar does this mean "Fortune and misfortune comes alternately"? The words are similar, but as far as I understand it, it has a completely different meaning.

Comment: It's not a "misquote", it's a paraphrasing.

Comment: @BlessedGeek This saying is around in various guises. Sometimes it's "the Lord"; sometimes it's "God"; sometimes it's even "the gods".

Comment: @fNek, a completely different meaning? Sometimes God takes away ("puts you down"), and sometimes he gives ("picks you up"). Perhaps the most significant nuance in the original scripture is that there are only two events described: the beginning and end of life. Of course, this doesn't apply to the commonly paraphrased version (which is the answer).

Comment: @MarcelTuring it's a misquote. Paraphrasing would keep the original meaning, which is: *Blessed be the name of the Lord.*

Comment: @BigHomie "the Lord gave, and the Lord hath taken away" does *not* mean "Blessed be the name of the Lord." Yes, the paraphrase is taken out of context, but otherwise its meaning is essentially intact.

Comment: (There's also the Tom Waits version, from "Step Right Up": "The large print giveth, and the small print taketh away.")

Comment: Answer is chosen already but isn't this mainly used when someone dies? In my opinion, this is mainly related to life/death situations.

Comment: I don't get it, this saying is the other way around, totally not equivalent to the OP one... how could you consider them to mean the same thing? Order matters!

Comment: If this is the Bible we're talking about, it wasn't written in English and there are many translations available: the two sentences are close enough, so I wouldn't say it's a misquote. If anything, it's a better translation than the translation you have quoted below it.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt, the phrase is from the Old Testament and is thus from Judaism. Though basically correct, it's more accurate to say most widely used English religious sayings are Judeo-Christian in origin.

Comment: @Huperniketes: I'm not sure I agree. Most English religious phrases are from Christianity. It's true that many things from Christianity are originally from Judaism, but the reason the phrases are common in English is that they are from Christianity, not that they are from Judaism. (By contrast, Talmudic expressions, which are from Judaism but not from Christianity, are not common among non-Jews. For example, you almost never hear a non-Jew quote R' Hillel's "If I am not for myself, who will be for me?")

Comment: @ruakh - it depends on your definition of "from". The book of Job came to the Western culture "from" the Jewish tradition "by way of" Christianity. I think that Huperniketes is right to say that "Judeo-Christian" might be the correct term; but when you say that the origin of an expression is "Christianity" it is usually assumed you are talking about the New Testament and the religious traditions that developed around Jesus of Nazareth - who was of course himself a Jew and well versed in the Old Testament.

Comment: @Floris: I'm not saying that "Judeo-Christian" is erroneous, I'm just disagreeing with Huperniketes' statement that "Judeo-Christian in origin" is "more accurate" than "based on Christianity". I would say instead that it's "equally accurate, but less precise". (Well, or differently imprecise, in that "based on" is rather vague as well. But if "based on Christianity" means "Christian in origin", then it's just as correct as "Judeo-Christian in origin".)

Comment: It is **staggeringly incorrect** to describe this as a misquote.  Many new users are unaware there's an "edit" button on answers where you can edit away whopping errors.

Comment: @Marcel -- it's not really "paraphrasing" - it's just a translation.  Any English version of that verse (or any other from bible books) is a translation.

Comment: From a perspective of Christian theology or comparative religion, the original text would be Hebrew. From the perspective of the English language, the KJV is in effect the original text, having a massively greater impact on the English language than any other translation.

Comment: This phrase's meaning is profoundly distinct from the Japanese phrase. The phrase from Job is a theodicy and an instruction for how to respond to profound loss: it argues that God is free to take away from us because any good thing we have was given to us by God to begin with. If your child dies, do not curse God, but bless him for ever giving children at all. The Japanese phrase is just about fortune: the wheel of fortune keeps turning and even if you have had some bad luck, you will have good luck again some day. The Job verse gives no reassurance that God will ever bless you again.

Comment: You folks are seriously commenting on how "Christian" a phrase's origin is and "paraphrase" vs "misquote" on this Q? Go post another Q. You kids sound silly now, pretending to be intelligent. Just plain silly.

Answer (score 38):

**[when one door closes, another opens](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/when_one_door_closes,_another_opens)**

> When one opportunity is lost, another opportunity soon becomes available.
>
> ---
>
> **Alternative forms**
>
> - when one door closes, another door opens
> - when one door closes, another one opens
> - when one door shuts, another opens

---

There are versions with "God" in it also:

- when God closes/shuts a door, he opens another
- when God closes/shuts a door, he opens a window

A less common one:

- when God closes/shuts a door, he opens a universe

Comment: This is quite close. One difference is that this typically refers to opportunities, not other kinds of misfortune. If your cat got hit by a truck, but eventually recovers, you probably wouldn't apply this saying.

Comment: @Paul: I agree it is usually used related to opportunities and this fits better to the OP's example also. Though, it can be used regarding to other misfortunes including your example because I heard people using this saying when talking about recoveries. I think it is a flexible proverb. The equivalent proverb does not have to include God and religious connotations also and this proverb can be used both with or without God.

Comment: This seems closest to the original intent to me, as in English, a god or gods would not usually be invoked in this scenario.

Comment: I do not know what the Japanese idiom is supposed to mean, but there's an apparent difference: in your expression the good thing follows the bad thing, in the Japanese idiom no such order is assumed, as far as I can tell with the limited information available. It would be interesting to know if the Japanese idiom could be used after someone wins the lottery, as a way of saying "tread carefully, behave well", and if so then your suggestion would not capture its spirit (speculating here).

Answer (score 22):

You win some and you lose some

Comment: Amazing suggestion.  Brilliant.

Answer (score 15):

In common UK English, there's 'What you gain on the swings, you lose on the roundabouts', which I often hear abbreviated to 'Oh well, swings and roundabouts'

Comment: I think it's, "What you lose on the swings, you make up for on the roundabouts." (As you point out, though, "swings and roundabouts" is far more common.)

Comment: What are "swings" in this context? I would expect it to have something to do with roadways/driving (to parallel "roundabouts"), but I don't know of any such meanings for the term.

Comment: @Marthaª it refers to playground swings and roundabouts (a merry-go-round)

Comment: @Will I'm pretty sure that it's racetracks, not playgrounds.

Comment: @chrylis as in horse racing?

Comment: Apparently it comes from [this poem](http://allpoetry.com/poem/8563049-Roundabouts-and-Swings-by-Patrick-R-Chalmers) "Roundabouts and Swings" where a fairground owner talks about how business is going.

Comment: @neil Alas, the Scottish socialist John Burns used the phrase in the [Parliamentary Debates](http://books.google.com/books?id=s-ATAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA670&dq=%22gain+on+the+swings%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=smhvU4TFN9ixyAT4mYLYAQ&ved=0CDoQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22gain%20on%20the%20swings%22&f=false) for May 1895, seventeen years before Chalmers' poem was published.

Comment: @StoneyB Fair enough - I did wonder if the poem seemed a little contrived.

Answer (score 14):

From classical times through the Renaissance, the western tradition was a *single* goddess, Fortuna, "Lady Luck", who turns men on her wheel, bringing them from misery to happiness and back again.

In Shakespeare's *King Lear*, for instance, the loyal Kent, when the villains lock him overnight in the stocks, composes himself to sleep with a prayer to Fortune to raise him to his former high estate:

> Fortune, good night,
>   Smile once more, turn thy wheel.

And when the villainous Edmund, who has risen from nonentity to preeminence, is slain by his brother, he concedes that he has been Fortune’s toy:

> The wheel is come full circle: I am here.

Here’s a medieval representation of Fortune turning her wheel:

[image]

The legend reads (in Frenchified Latin), on the left, *I will reign*; on top, *I am reigning*; on the right, *I have reigned*, and on the bottom, *I am without a kingdom*.

Comment: The wheel (of fortune) which turns (full circle), is also used in Italian. *La ruota gira prima o poi* which means if things are bad now, be patient and wait, sooner or later it will turn in your favour.

Comment: Interestingly, the phrase "come full circle" is still quite common, while references to the wheel and Fortune are few and far between these days. *(At least in my experience.)*  It's good to know where it comes from.

Comment: This is a truly beautiful post, but it appears to be completely unrelated to the question, and/or offers no suggestions at all about a possible answer??

Comment: @JoeBlow - The suggestion in it, as I understand it, is "The wheel has come full circle" and variations thereof.  It's not very explicit, though, and could probably use an edit to clarify.

Answer (score 6):

"Some days you get the elevator and some days you get the shaft"

Answer (score 3):

To translate this expression, you need to cope with the very different attitudes towards divinity of Japanese and 'Western' culture. When a Japanese expression talks about the kami, it's in a different atmosphere than when an English expression talks about God.

There are many kami, they come and go. The Japanese expression suggests that there are many powers in the world and that different ones are influential at different times.

The monotheistic view is very different: there's one deity. It's very different for the one and only deity to dish out varying results than for random encounters with different kami to result in different outcomes.

Thus, you might want to stick to expressions that don't involve God, but rather talk about fate, or luck, or use the passive. I think you're better off avoiding divinity altogether, as you lose a lot more translation quality by referencing the very different divinity than you gain by maintaining the reference to divinity at all.

Comment: Exactly correct.  IMO you've explained why "The Lord giveth and the Lord taketh away" is not so good, and "windows close/open" variants are much better here.

Answer (score 2):

It's an interesting question, because the English language has a significantly monotheistic background, so **references to one god for this and one god for that are not common**.

Your question made me think of the line from the song "**He who made kittens put snakes in the grass**", but once again this is the same god, not different gods.

However, I think that the monotheistic quotes *are* the English equivalent for the saying you have referred to: it's what English say when referring to the same phenomenon, even though the religious background to it is different.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes You Eat The Bear, Sometimes The Bear Eats You

(The quote from [one great movie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Lebowski) to lighten down this solemn thread.)

Comment: This is quoted sometimes while starting up the Slack app, which I quite like ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your question reminded me of a Biblical quotation that I remembered from my childhood, but which, after a bit of searching online, has turned out to be just another biblical misquotation ("The Lord giveth, and the Lord taketh away").

Regardless, the misquotation I was thinking of is based on Job 1:21, which says:

> "Naked I came from my mother’s womb, and naked I will depart. **The Lord gave and the Lord has taken away**; may the name of the Lord be praised."

As an atheist who has not systematically studied the Bible, I don't pretend to have any insight into the significance of this verse. But the misquotation (and variations on it) does seem to be pretty well-established in today's Anglo-Saxon culture.

Answer (score 1):

This too shall pass.

Admittedly not English in origin, but common in English. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_too_shall_pass

Answer (score 0):

**Take the good with the bad** seems to fit.

If you'll excuse a crude example:

> My wife was being a real bitch this morning, but the sex we had last night was excellent, so I guess you have to take the good with the bad.

Comment: Another excellent idea.