# Looking for a verb that means the same as this proverb.

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

After black clouds, clear weather.

I'm looking for a verb for 'clear weather' here. I want to comfort someone but by using a verb that carries the meaning of this. That there will be relief and comfort at the end.

Don't get/weigh much down on yourself, it will 'clear weather'.

I'm looking for a suitable verb or phrasal verb that be fitting.

Comment: "Don't get down on yourself, it will clear" or "it will brighten".

Comment: Related question, [Are there English equivalents to the Japanese saying, “There’s a god who puts you down as well as a god who picks you up”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/169134/are-there-english-equivalents-to-the-japanese-saying-there-s-a-god-who-puts-yo/169425#169425).

Comment: This too shall pass

Comment: Something wrong with *get better*?  Does the answer have to evoke weather clearing?  Storms *break* the way that tides *ebb*.

Comment: You mean like the weather is "clearing"?

Answer (score 1):

**Brighten up** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/brighten+up)

> 3. To become happier; improve one's mood or outlook
>
> *"He brightened up after you began talking with him."*
>
> 4. To make someone happier or more cheerful
>
> *"The sunny weather brightened up the tired travelers."*
> *"A cool glass of lemonade would brighten me up right now."*

**Darkest hour is just before the dawn** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/darkest+hour+is+just+before+the+dawn)
and It's always darkest just before the dawn.

> *Prov.* When things are extremely bad, it may signal that they are about to get much better.
>
> *Jill: I feel like giving up. I don't have a job, my boyfriend left me, and they're raising the rent for my apartment.
>
> Jane: It's always darkest just before the dawn."*

Related quote from film *The Dark Knight*

> The night is darkest just before the dawn. And I promise you, the dawn is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,

***fair up***

> fair up/fair off: *Chiefly Southern U.S.* (*meteorology*) To clear: *They said it was going to fair off later on, but it didn't*. [YourDictionary](http://www.yourdictionary.com/fair-off#QkMCrPF7s3u7x0Qx.99)
>
> *South Midland and Southern U.S.* (*of the weather*) To clear:
>   *It's supposed to fair off toward evening*. [Random House](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fair)
>
> Southern ***fair off*** and ***fair up***, meaning "to become clear," were originally Northeastern terms and were brought to the South as settlement expanded southward and westward. They are now "regionalized to the South," according to Craig M. Carver, author of American Regional Dialects. These phrases may have prompted the coining of ***milding*** and ***milding down***, noted respectively in Texas and Virginia by the Dictionary of American Regional English. [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/fair)
>
> *Don't get so down on yourself, things will **fair up***.

***let up***

> : Improve: If ​bad ​weather or an ​unpleasant ​situation ​lets up, it ​stops or ​improves: *When the ​rain ​lets up we'll go for a ​walk*. [COD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/let-up)
>
> *Don't get so down on yourself, things will **let up***.

***ease up***

> ease up/ease off: To gradually ​stop or ​become less: *At last the ​rain ​began to ​ease off*. [COD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/ease-up)
>
> *Don't get so down on yourself, things will **ease up***.